# How to preserve styles of embedded widget?

Tags: php, html, css, include, stylesheet

How to make an external PHP *widget* page have its own CSS.
The catch is - when the external page is `include`d it's been affected by the stylesheet of the *host* page.

The included page is actually a comments 'widget' (with his own .css file, about 30 lines, not much) and the height and width flexibility are a MUST HAVE.

The **PHP** `include` was so far the best solution, but I lost my hair adjusting its CSS file to fit / **null** (adding/excluding/ styles) any possible host web page.

<sub>Example:</sub>
 if the host page has styles for `img` borders I have to null them from the widget's style.css, same for `H3`, `P`, and so on.

How would you preserve a widget stylesheet from being affected by the *host* page styles, beside using **iframe**?

Comment: Now it is possible with Shadow DOM: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38919623/4600982

Comment: @Supersharp gotcha thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You know CSS is a client-side thing; it doesn't know about PHP and how the page has generated on the server.

You have got to focus on the final resulting HTML and redefine tags and classes and IDs so that your desired style rules apply to right elements.

You can limit the scope of CSS rules by surrounding that part in a div with a unique ID or class and use it in your CSS selectors so they wouldn't apply to elements outside of that div.

Or if you can't do that you have to use stronger rules to override included ones for your other elements. Which will be a little messy, but you can override styles applied to an element using several techniques like !important or having more selector parts.

For example, in both of the below samples, the second rule will overwrite the first one:

```
#comments .link { color: red; } /* Included page rule */
#header .link { color: blue !important; }
```

or

```
#comments .link { color: red; } /* Included page rule */
#header div a.link { color: blue; }
```

Comment: This may be the best answer of all (and I answered, too) because it's how your CSS should be designed.  Take a page with the widget included.  Code your CSS as you want it for the whole page, including the widget.  If you want the widget image borders red instead of the site's blue, code them that way.  Including extra CSS for a widget that's not always present is a tiny penalty compared to knocking out existing rules and including another CSS file.  Style your site like the widget is always there and you're covered.  You are using a master stylesheet for the site, right?  :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to apply a mini CSS reset on your included code.  Surround your code in a unique id, like so:

```
<div id="widget">
    <!--your code here-->
</div>
```

Now apply the reset to everything inside this, using a basic CSS reset like Eric Meyer's, available here: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Now, apply your own CSS.  Nearly all outside CSS will be wiped out, and yours will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your widget code in a div with an id. Then prefix each CSS selector used in the widget with that selector.

ex.

```
<div id="widget"><p class="nav">hello</p></div>
```

instead of,

```
.nav{
// styles
}
```

do

```
#widget.nav{
// styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS Styles prioritize like this:

1. Browser default
2. External style sheet
3. Internal style sheet (in the head section)
4. Inline style (inside an HTML element)

Depending on how much CSS you need to apply, you could writ it on the "head" tag.
Hope the suggestion helps.

Comment: Thanks all the suggestions helped.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, your included page has some CSS rules such as:

```
div {/*rules*/};
p {/*rules*/};
```

and so on.

You should change your CSS selectors from the most general ones (div selects *all* the divs in the page) to the most particular ones (use them in this order: [id, class, child-selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)) in order for your rules to apply only to your included elements.

For example, say your included page is wrapped in a div, the PHP code would be:

```
<div id="my_page">
    <?php include "myPage.php"; ?>
</div>
```

Then, all your rules for the page should refer only to the children of the element with the id `my_page`:

Instead of

```
div {/*rules*/};
```

you'll have

```
#my_page div {/*rules*/};
```