# how to protect embedded div style not to be overridden by website style

Tags: css, sass, less, webpack, shadow-dom

I have div with its own style. I embedded this div on other website.

```
<div id="scoped-div">
  <style>
    label {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>

  <label> Scoped div </label>
</div>
```

But I face problem, my div style is overridden by website style. I don't want to use `iframe`. Except for the use of `iframe` is there any other way to protect my div style by external style changes?

Comment: Use a more specific selector - one that includes the ID of your element. (That should do it for most situations; there might still be edge cases where a site manages to overwrite your style via `!important` or something like that. You could include `!important` for all your properties as well, but that might lead to problems within your component as well if not done carefully.)

Comment: @CBroe I wrote inline style with `!important` flag like this: `<label style="color:green !important"></label>`, but even this can be overriden by using style: `label[style] { color: yellow !important;}` written below my `div`

Comment: _“but even this can be overriden”_ – of course it can - _because_ it is not your site, you can’t expect anything else. If you want absolute independence of styles, then you need to separate your content completely from the parent document, like with an iframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request is exactly what [Shadow DOM](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/shadow/) makes possible:

1. attach a Shadow DOM to the element you want to protect (here:
   `#scope-div`),
2. put the HTML code you want to protect in the Shadow DOM,
3. clone it from a `<template>` element to get it easy (optional).

That's it!

```js
var div = document.querySelector( "#scoped-div" )
var template = document.querySelector( "template" )

var sh
if ( 'attachShadow' in div )
  sh = div.attachShadow( { mode: "closed" } )  //Shadow DOM v1
else
  sh = div.createShadowRoot()                 //Shadow DOM v0 fallback

sh.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode( true ) )
```

```html
<template>
  <style>
    label {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>

  <label> Scoped div </label>
</template>

<div id="scoped-div">
</div>
```

Comment: You'll find more infos on Shdow DOM here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/shadowdom/

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to fully protect your styles. But you can try the following:

- Try to specify your elements selectors as specific as possible (e.g. with attributes and IDs)
- Use inline styles
- Use `!important` (but be careful with a broad [use of importants](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/))

Comment: Andreas thank you for your response, we discuss this situations in comments